# Question of Binomial distribution minimal and maximal k

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I am confused to understand and to find maximal $\ k=k(n,p)$ and minimal $\ k=k(n,p)$ for a binomial distribution question. Below are my question:

Q1. Let $\Pr=binomial(n,p)$ . Check that $\Pr(i+1)=\frac{p}{1−p}⋅\frac{n−i}{i+1}⋅Pr(i)$ for all $\ i=0,1,…,n−1$ and find the maximal $\ k=k(n,p)$, such that $\ Pr(0),…,Pr(k)$ is a strictly increasing sequence: $\ k(n,p)=$ (answer to be filled in)

Q2. Let $\Pr=binomial(n,p)$. Find the minimal $\ k=k(n,p)$, such that $\Pr(k),Pr(k+1),…$ is a strictly decreasing sequence: $\ k(n,p)=$ (answer to be filled in)

To understand these two questions, I try to find a clue from Wikipedia binomial distribution. The closest thing that I found is monotone increasing and monotone decreasing under [Probability mass function section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function). However, it seems like I cannot apply it directly. Therefore, I would like to ask that did I understand this question correctly?

Comment: The main feature of binomial an d Poisson distribution $f(k)$ is a single maximum function of discrete variable $k$. The position of the max $k_0$ is called the mode of the distribution. I dont think that there is anything like minimal!

Comment: Did you already go through the calculation of Pr(i+1), to start?  Since these are sequences that first step is leading you towards the solution sought.